# Is it possible find the probability that $\cos(\pi t)\leq 1/2$?, with $t\geq0$?

Tags: probability

If $P(\cos(\pi t)\leq 1 )=1$ and $P(\cos(\pi t)\leq -1 )=0$.

Is it possible to intuit that $\cos (t \pi)$ has a uniform distribution?, How can I find $P(\cos(\pi t)\leq 1/2)$?

Comment: I think you assume that $t$ has a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos{(t\pi)}$ is not uniformally distributed unless $t$ is distributed in a non standard way. If $t\sim U(0,1)$ for example, then $X=\cos{(t\pi)}$ is distributed such that
$$\begin{align}
P(X\le x)
&=P(\cos{(t\pi)}\le x)\\
&=P(t\le1-\frac{\arccos{(x)}}\pi)\\
&=\begin{cases} 
      0 &x\lt-1\\
      1-\frac{\arccos{(x)}}\pi & -1\leq x\leq 1 \\
      1 & x\gt1 
   \end{cases}\\
\end{align}$$
So the answer would be 
$$P(\cos{(t\pi)}\le \frac12)=1-\frac{\arccos{(\frac12})}{\pi}=1-\frac13=\frac23$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll obtain [Peter Foreman's result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3178908) in a slightly different way.

Let's split the circle in quadrants.

- In the first quadrant, for angles in $[0; \pi /2]$, or for $t \in [0; 1/2]$, the cosine is less than $1/2$ for $t \in [1/3; 1/2]$, since the cosine is a decreasing function in the first quadrant and $\cos \frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{1}{2}$.
- In the second quadrant, for angles in $[\pi /2; \pi]$, or for $t \in [1/2; 1]$, the cosine is negative.
- The third quadrant is like the second.
- And the fourth quadrant is like the first for $t \in [3/2; 5/3]$.

So, for the angles in $[0; 2\pi[$, i.e., for $t \in [0; 2[$, we have that $\cos (\pi t) \leq 1/2$ for $t \in [1/3; 5/3]$.

If $t$ were uniformly distributed in $[0; 2[$ the probability would be 
$$\frac{\frac{5}{3} - \frac{1}{3}}{2-0} = \frac{\frac{4}{3}}{2} = \frac{2}{3} $$

---

Now we can expand this reasoning to an arbitrary interval.
Let $T$ be some positive number, i.e., $T>0$, and we want the probability of $\cos (\pi t) \leq 1/2$ for $t \in [0; T]$ obtained with uniform probability.

We will need two auxiliary numbers $R$ which is the largest even number less than or equal to $T$, i.e., $R = 2 \lfloor T/2 \rfloor$ and $S = T - R \in [0; 2)$. And let $C \in [0; 4/3]$ be
$$
C = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 0               & \  \textrm{if} \ S \in \left[ 0; \frac{1}{3} \right] \\
 S - \frac{1}{3} & \  \textrm{if} \ S \in \left( \frac{1}{3}; \frac{5}{3} \right) \\
 \frac{4}{3}     & \  \textrm{if} \ S \in \left[ \frac{5}{3}; 2 \right)
\end{array}
\right.
$$

The probability is 
$$\frac{\frac{2}{3} R + C}{T}$$
which approaches $\frac{2}{3}$ when $T \to +\infty$.